# Every Second - Disk Filled - compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, disk

Since a day, my Google Cloud server is running this process that I think is responsible for my disk filling at high speed (at this time it was full). Any idea if that will be responsible for my full disk? and/or how to stop that process? Thanks.
Below I leave an image with the list of processes.

Process List
[image]

Comment: Howdy and welcome to StackOverflow.  If I'm understanding that screen shot correctly, this is NOT a list of processes (Linux processes) on your VM but is rather a list of operations performed externally on your VM.  I think we need some more info.  Are you talking about Compute Engine instances?  Is it a Linux OS?  If the disk is filling, what is taking up the space (which files are growing)?

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the screenshot it seems the user leacirolani@gmail.com working on the project and if you click on the message (  compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata) you will find the information what kind of operation was there, is the message relevant to the issue of disk full quickly or not.

You should get information like below: (check for your case)

++

Operation type

compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata (check for your case what kind of operation going on)

Target type
Instances (check for your case)

Target
(check for your case, it seems the project you have)

Target ID
(check for your case)

Progress

?%

User
(check for your case, who is the user)

Insert time
Dec 19, 2019, 7:01:51 PM
Start time
Dec 19, 2019, 7:01:51 PM
End time
Dec 19, 2019, 7:01:51 PM

Equivalent REST

++

- Did you check in the stackdriver log if there is any information about the disk full?
- Is there have any info in Serial port log about OOM (Out Of Memory) ?

Need more information to know why disk becomes full very quickly as there could be several reasons.

You could follow the document [1] if you are facing an issue on VM instance unreachable due to full disk.

[1]-- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances